# Should i wait or call after 2 weeks of application?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process

I have applied for a federal job that I am extremely interested in. I already contacted the HR there by phone within 5 days of applying, to check on the progress.

I was told that within 2 weeks they will start calling for interviews. The 2 weeks ends today. In the meantime, I did receive an email stating that my application is under review... Should I call back, or wait? I'm getting nervous!

Comment: If you call back, they'll give you the runaround,put you on hold and tell you that your application is under review.  What are you trying to accomplish by calling at this point in time? Do you have an objective?

Comment: I am not 100% sure. I just want to know if I am getting call for interview. I just want to let them know that I am really interested in the position and hopefully they look at my resume. If they do, I am quite confident that I match pretty much 100% for the position. It is very rare for a position like that to come by.

Comment: They said your application is under review. This means, they  haven't finished reviewing it yet. You don't expect them to call you for an interview until they have reviewed your application and others' applications, right?

Comment: However they did said about 2 weeks which ends today

Comment: One more time: what does the statement "your application is under review" mean?

Comment: If you are that eager to call, don't let me stop you. There are no real negative consequences to you calling anyway. The worst that happens is that you waste some time off your life and end up with that "your application is under review" message..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling too much can sometimes be good, sometimes be bad. You did mention that you've gotten an email saying that your application is under review - so yay, they have a system in place to actually communicate with applicants.

I personally would wait until Monday morning, and call then. Reiterate how very interested you are in this job, and ask a) when they think you might next hear from them; and b) their preferred method of contact. (They may prefer email, they may prefer phone, it varies.) That both re-establishes your interest, and gives them the courtesy of asking their preferences.

After that point, contact again one business day after any milestones they set out - or, if you get an email address, ping them once a week. (I say that because emails can be read when they have the time. Phone calls...are more of a "respond-to-it-RIGHT-NOW" thing, and so can be perceived as taking more of their time to take the call.

Comment: When can calling too much be bad.. I guess i am not thinking straight with nervouseness

Comment: If they perceive your checking in as nagging, if it starts to annoy them...it's too much. You have to find that delicate balance between "showing positive follow-through and enthusiasm" and "being over-eager." Find out what they think is enough time to check in, and work with their schedule so that they see: oh, this person not only has all the skills needed for this role, they work really well with people.

Comment: this post is rather hard to read (wall of text). Would you mind [edit]ing it into a better shape?

Answer (score 1):

Call. Despite this being a large govt dept employers want keen people with enthusiasm. I employed many people over the years and I would always consider those who appeared enthusiastic.

Perhaps you could walk in and say "Look I've just thought of another reason why I'm suited for this job and I've added it to my CV, could I give you this updated copy?" - Add a coffee, a muffin and a nice smile and you will be remembered.

In a competitive job market employers enthusiasm will trump a lot of things. I have never seen an employer scoff at someone for being too enthusiastic. I say go for it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have to take the other tack here. HR Departments do not like or appreciate people who call frequently. The Federal government generally moves slowly in HR terms; it can take months to go through all the applications and determine who is considered highly qualified. Bugging the people doing this is a good way to go to the bottom of the file of applications to be reviewed. This is not showing intiative or enthusiam (the hiring offical will never know you called), this is being a pest. The person looking at the app may have thousands of applications for various postions to go through. I remember one time we we were hiring, we had 900 applications for that one position alone. The HR person is probably trying to go through the applications for multiople postions.

The truth is there is nothing you can do to speed up a government hiring process unless the hiring manager knows you and wants you and even then it is really difficult. They have a much more structured process than private industry and I have seen candidates the hiring manager wanted to hire from personal knowldege get turned down because HR would not rate them as qualified.

Since they told you they are reviewing your application, you know they got it. If you get told you are not qualifed for the position, then you should see if you can speak to the HR person to find out why. This is a time when you should contact them, not when waiting for a response. Often they make mistakes and a little explanation can go a long way towards correcting this. Be aware though that when they say things like needs 4 years of experience or equivalent education, they are not going to think you are qualifed on only 3 years and 9 months. They tend to be much less flexible on requirements than private industry.

I assure you that any company or government agency that is interested in your application will contact you. Not hearing from them is generally a sign that you are not in consideration. However, since the government moves so slowly. not hearing from them in only two weeks means nothing. It could be months before they get back to you as there are multiple things that can affect the date including govvernment-wide hiring freezes.

In general once HR gets through with the applications, they pass them on to a hiring manager who may appoint a team of people to go throuhg the applications and determine who to interview. The HR filtering is just to remove the unqualifed from thestack, so the hiring officals have fewer applications to look at. Again it may take weeks for them to set up interviews as they all have full time jobs to and making the time is often difficult. HR often will not let candidates know they are being turned down until the hiring people have determined who is going to be interviewed. This is becasue sometinmes the hiring officals don't like the chocies and go ask for the applications that were filtered out.  Of course here in the US, we are heading towords a major holiday and people who might be looking at these things both in HR and the actual department may be on vacation, so that tends to slow things further.